# Why ViewBag is empty?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

On my MVC project I have two forms that on submit I want to redirect to the same ThankYou page.

On the controllers of the 2 forms I saved in the ViewBag the text for the ThankYou page.

On the Controller I set the ViewBage like this:

```
if (result == "success")
   {
   ViewBag.ThankYouText = "We have received your Contact us request."

   return RedirectToAction("Index", "ThankYou",ViewBag);
   }
```

And on the ThankYou View I get it:

```
 <p>ViewBag.ThankYouText</p>
```

But I keep getting nothing on my ThankYou page.

I'm new to pure MVC so I must have done something wrong, any idea?

Comment: `ViewBag` is for passing data from a controller to a view. Your redirecting to another method and as soon as you do so, the value is lost. One option is to use `TempData` to pass the method to the other method. Another is to use `return RedirectToAction("Index", "ThankYou", new { message = "..." });` and in the `ThankYou()` method, add a parameter `string message`

Comment: Yes, you need to use `TempData` to pass data from one controller Action to another, May be in your second action you can set the viewbag, else TempData will work too

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for the idea I think that it's in a way it's nicer than to use `tempData`, but I'm just note sure how to get the value in the View?

Comment: If your method is `public ActionResult ThankYou(string message)` then you can either assign the value to `ViewBag` (e.g. `ViewBag.ThankYouText = message;` and use `<p>@ViewBag.ThankYouText</p>`, or preferably use a view model and assign the value to a property of your view model and use `<p>@Model.ThankYouText</p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not pass ViewBag value from one controller to other. It is supposed to use for passing data from controller to view only.

If you want to pass data from controller to controller you can use TempData.

Change your controller as below:

```
if (result == "success")
   {
   TempData["ThankYouText"] = "We have received your Contact us request."    
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "ThankYou");
   }
```

Change your view as below:

```
 <p>@TempData["ThankYouText"]</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

change code like this

```
TempData["ThankYouText"] = "We have received your Contact us request.";

return RedirectToAction("Index", "your controller");
```

in your index method

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{ 
     ViewBag.ThankYouText = TempData["ThankYouText"]; return View(); 
}
```

and use @ keyword before ViewBag.ThankYouText